# Spring: Trouble wiring up a datasource in a Junit test

Tags: spring, junit

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.M2.  I'm writing some JUnit 4 tests to test some database functionality, but I'm having trouble wiring up my datasource.  In my JUnit class, I have …

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, 
    classes={DataSource.class, WebLeadsDAOImpl.class})
public class TestDB {
...
@Qualifier("mycoSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * Using a single lead lookup should speed up our testing queries.
 * <p>
 * The lead is is 8104051
 * </p>
 */
@Before
public void prep() { 
    assertNotNull(sessionFactory);
    ...
}
```

but the "sessionFactory" object is repeatedly null.  Here is how I'm trying to configure it …

```
@Lazy
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:oracle.properties")
public class DataSource {
…

@Bean(name="mycoSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws Exception {
   final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBuilder()
        .setDataSource(dataSource())
        .setHibernateProperties(databaseProperties())
        .setPackagesToScan("com.criticalmass.systems.leadsmonitor.domain")
        .setSchemaUpdate(false)
        .buildSessionFactory();
   return sessionFactory;
}
```

The reason I don't just use "@Autowired" is because I have two SessionFactory beans.  Any ideas why my datasource isn't wiring up correctly?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your updated suggestion, but the answer turns out to be I had forgotten to add

```
@Autowired
```

before the member field.  When I did that, everything worked great. -

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like you missed to annotate your test class by @ContextConfiguration.</s>

---

I guess I have it: you missed the annotation that triggers Spring to inject something. 
Just add:

- `@Inject` or,
- `@Resource` or,
- `@Autowired`

to the variable declaration of sessionFactory in your test case.

Comment: I edited my response to show that my JUnit class already had the "@ContextConfiguration" annotation pointing at the appropriate class.  In fact, I have verified through logging that the SessionFactory bean generation method I listed above is being called.  Any other ideas?